# FINRA API in Python or R?

Tags: python, r

I am very new to the coding and now learning more about Python for financial analysts matters. I am trying to figure out how I can download equity short interest from FINRA because I could not find any similar articles or cases discussing about getting the financial data from FINRA. Would be great if somebody could clarify me that It is possible or not to do it in python or R.

Answer (score 1):

FINRA has an API developer portal that outlines for their API products. It seems Short Interest Data can be fetched using their Market Transparency API (More info here: https://developer.finra.org/products/market-transparency).

You can use either R (jsonlite and httr libraries) or Python (requests and json modules).

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure where to fix the codes for getting the whole dataset for the certain period of time, e.g 2018.06.01 to 2021.03.05. The original code is in below curl command to download only for a day.

curl -L -d "{ "compareFilters": [ { "compareType": "EQUAL", "fieldName": " settlementDate", "fieldValue": " 2018-06-15" } ] ,"limit":5 } " -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST https://api.finra.org/data/group/otcMarket/name/EquityShortInterest

Comment: But I was able to change that curl command into the below json format to run in python.

headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json', }

data = '{ "compareFilters": [ { "compareType": "EQUAL", "fieldName": " settlementDate", "fieldValue": " 2018-06-15" } ] ,"limit":5 } '

response = requests.post('https://api.finra.org/data/group/otcMarket/name/EquityShortInterest', headers=headers, data=data)